# How JVM knows line numbers during runtime?

Tags: java, line-numbers, jvm-bytecode

When a .java file is compiled, it produces a .class file containing bytecode. JVM takes that bytecode and executes it. Byte during this step, if an exception is thrown, there is also a mention of in which line did this error occurred in source code. But the line numbers in bytecode and source code will be completely different and bytecode also does not store line numbers during compilation since I did not find any mnemonics related to it (and also storing line numbers would simply increase the code size). So can someone tell me how JVM gets the exact line number in the source code where the exception was thrown.

Comment: The compiler generates debugging information - so your statement "bytecode also does not store line numbers" is not correct. It does not keep the original line count and stuff, but the information is present.

Comment: Read about the `-g` option in the _javadoc_ for [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9)

Comment: @Abra I just took a glance at it.. I think I'm too early to ask this question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JVM specification provides a reference for the format of class files (bytecode). The line numbers are stored in an attribute [`LineNumberTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12). You can also try running the following Java disassembler command (`javap` provided by the JDK) on a certain `.class` file to see them:

```
javap -l MyClass.class
```